# What to do now that "youtube-dl.exe -U" yields "ERROR: can't find the current version. Please try again later."?

Tags: youtube-dl

I used to be able to run the command:

```
youtube-dl.exe -U
```

To update youtube-dl. But now, it says:

```
ERROR: can't find the current version. Please try again later.
```

As always when an error message of any kind, anywhere, tells you to "try again later", it never works later. It's permanent. That's like a law of nature.

I have searched for this and found discussions about it. Those discussions, however, don't actually offer any kind of real explanation/solution. Which is also like a law of nature whenever I have any computer issue; nobody knows how to fix it, and it just happens for seemingly no reason and without me ever doing anything to provoke it.

```
youtube-dl.exe --version
```

Gives:

```
2020.07.28
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for YouTube-dl?

Comment: Successfully upgraded the `youtube-dl` executable version (`youtube-dl.exe`) from version `2020.07.28` to `2020.09.06` using `-U` just today. So this appears to be working, at least in some instances. My thoughts would be that this was perhaps a temporary issue with the update servers or there is/was some connection issue perhaps on your end.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr use

```
youtube-dl -U --no-check-certificate
```

There's some certificate issue, likely at your end.  Some folks have tracked down a bad certificate on their systems and deleted it, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: This isn't the "right" way to fix the problem, but knowing that updates work without the certificate check—as they did indeed for me—was important information! (Just be forewarned that in terms of security risk, this is similar to downloading the update via http rather than https.)

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your Windows CA certstore, by loading the certmgr.msc (certificates manager) snap-in:

[image: Cert Mgmt UI]

Expand Intermediate CAs -> Certificates, then sort stored intermediate certificates by Expiration Date; then proceed to delete ALL the expired ones (you may want to export them to a PFX first).

Try updating YouTube-DL again.

Source/more info: [youtube-dl -U == ERROR: can't find the current version. Please try again later.](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/27003)

Comment: That'd be great if one has a "Windows CA certstore"...

Comment: Well, everyone using Windows has one. :)

Comment: That was the point of my comment... not everyone uses Windows.

Comment: @JohnLittle So the answer is invalid because it doesn't work in every OS?

Comment: @Techie007 I'd just like it to not assume Windows.  Maybe just "If this is on Windows...".